# Copy and chown a file for every user

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a way to copy a README.txt file from /root into every /home/{USER}/public_html dir using CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (assuming BASH):

```
pushd /home;
for file in ./*; do
    cp /root/README.txt /home/$file/public_html/
    chown $file /home/$file/public_html/README.txt
    # this is a cheat, assuming that every user's name equals his home directory
done;
popd
```

Comment: That covers the copying, but doesn't get to the chown part of the question.

Comment: @killermist I updated the answer to include chown as well.

Comment: That looks like what I would have used as a pragmatic solution.  Though, yes, that is definitely a cheat and may do the wrong case for some users/dirs.

Answer (score 0):

Shell independent, you can use "find" as in...

```
find /home -name public_html -maxdepth 2 -exec cp /root/README.html {} \;
```